# Using Conda Environments with a 'read-only' base installation

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment, miniconda

I have installed miniconda-3 via the bash script on a linux system with many users. I set this base installation to read-only for all. Ideally, most users will simply run the following to run their python apps on their system.

```sh
eval "$(/path/to/bin/conda shell.bash hook)"
```

In the event they need custom packages, they can create a conda clone via

```sh
conda create -p /path/to/new/env --clone $CONDA_PREFIX
```

However, in this case user's environments are still using the base conda and its configuration which causes permissions errors if the user runs `conda install ...` like the following:

```
NotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to a required path.
  path: /path/to/miniconda3/pkgs/cache/9e0f62c3.json
```

Is there a way to cause the new environment to use its own `pkg_dirs` and `env_dirs` without the user needing to manually change them?

Comment: Why not have a shared pkg_dirs ?

Comment: To some extent, I'm unfamiliar with the inner details of Conda and am trying to avoid users from fouling up the base installation. Would opening the pkg_dirs to write-all lead to such a situation? I'm not sure for what exactly this area is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a shared `pkg_dirs`. In short, this is a cache directory. When running `conda install`, it downloads packages from the public channels into this directory and then installs them.

The advantage of having this folder the same for each user will be that it will speed up installation as it will reduce downloads if packages are already in the cache from another user.

See [this guide](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/shared-pkg-cache/) about details. Basically, you just have to add

```
pkgs_dirs:
    - /path/to/shared_directory
```

to your `.condarc`